# How to make behavior of the bubble button same as Facebook messenger Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

The Facebook messenger chat bubble that we see on top of our screen has the behavior that if I move that icon on the right side it automatically sticking to the right side of the screen. If I move it to the left part of the screen it will automatically move to the left wall. So in moves horizontally to the end of the needed side. So I need to implement the same behavior. Are there any people that had experience in doing that kind of things?

That is based on overlay service that implements onTouchListener

```
class BubbleService : Service(), View.OnTouchListener
```

With this in onTouch we can get coordinates and do any actions we want

```
override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent)
```

And with the help of windowManager and params that we get from event we can create new behavior. Like this

```
windowManager.updateViewLayout(bubbleButton, params)
```

Thats the screen I'm talking about
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: this could potentially be a really interesting question, if you include some code, at least just the very basics of what you've done so far would be enough

Comment: @a_local_nobody I have added some code and logic to show overview of how it works